# how to translate fedora yum source into RHEL?

Tags: linux, desktop, yum

I use fedora 13 on my laptop, and I use 'yum' to install "recordmydesktop" just for fun.One day, my boss ask me to install "recordmydesktop" into his computer (whose operating system is Redhat Enterprise 5.2).
The yum in his computer does not work! I can't `yum install recordmydesktop`! I know the reason is in the yum's source, but how can I use the source in fedora to the yum in RHEL(Redhat Enterprise)?

Answer (score 0):

try rpmforge as repository... edit one file in /etc/repo.d and add as repository rpmforge...this should work